# Can't extract substring from string using regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, string

My first post here and it "obviously" has to be about regexp (the nightmare of all beginner devs)

I have a string: `s = "Shadowborn Apostle \r\nCreature — Human Cleric \r\nA deck can have any number Of \r\ncards named Shadowborn Apostle. \r\ne, Sacrifice six creatures named \r\nShadowborn Apostle: Search your \r\nlibrary for a Demon creature card \r\nand put it onto the battlefield. Then \r\nshuffle your library. \r\n"`

I would like to extract only this part `Shadowborn Apostle(space)`

I use .match to get the substring I want: `s.match(/^[^\\]+/)`

Unfortunately, MatchData = the whole string. And I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex [`^[^\\]+`](https://regex101.com/r/BN01oH/1) matches from the start of the string until it encounters the first backslash, including the whitespace because the negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matches not a backslash one or more times.

Maybe you can match any character one or more times non greedy `.+?` and use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) [`^.+?(?= \\r)`](http://rubular.com/r/VgPHGHoGD3)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/YWQB76555)

If you want to match `Shadowborn Apostle` followed by a whitespace in the text you could also use a word boundary `\b` at the start to make sure it is not part of a longer match and use a positive lookahead at the end `(?= )` to assert what follows is a whitespace.

[`\bShadowborn Apostle(?= )`](http://rubular.com/r/fvzsfCRYoP)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PUI49951)

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves my problem.

All I had to do, in my case, is to properly use `.scan` method instead of match/gsub etc. (which made me ask the question - I wasn't sure which method I should use)

Also, your regex is obviously much cleaner. Even if I used mine I'd still have to remove the trailing white space.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a problem - an empty array when I try to run .scan on the string: Demo [http://tpcg.io/mcb7Ry]

Comment: The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027321/ruby-scan-method-returns-empty-using-regex Your regex used \\r which was incorrectly parsed by Ruby's method for some reason. Thanks again!

Comment: The OP wants to return a string that ends with a space character if the space immediately precedes the line feed character, `\r`. That will not be done if the lookahead `(?= \r)` (not `(?= \\r)`) is used. Also you should not refer to "whitespace" when you mean "space", as they are not the same.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for your comment. I have removed my previous comment and will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `/^[^\\]+/` attempts to match one or more characters at the beginning of a line that are not backslashes. The backslash character (ASCII 92) is written `92.chr #=> "\\"`, whereas the line feed character (ASCII 13) is written `13.chr #=> "\r"`.<sup>1</sup>

You therefore want `/\A[^\r]+/`.

Note that I've used the *beginning of string* anchor, `\A`, rather than the *beginning of line* anchor, `^`. Consider the following.

```
"\r\ndog \r".match(/\A[^\r]+/) #=> nil
"\r\ndog \r".match(/^[^\r]+/)  #=> #<MatchData "dog ">
```

Whether to use `\A` or `^` depends on what you want to achieve. Henceforth I will assume it is `\A` that you want. (You should make that clear, however, by editing the question. As written, the desired substring need not start at the beginning of the string or a line.)

Continuing,

```
r = /\A[^\r]+/
m = s.match(r) #=> #<MatchData "Shadowborn Apostle ">
m[0] #=> "Shadowborn Apostle "
```

or (in place of `m[0]`):

```
$&   #=> "Shadowborn Apostle "
```

or simply:

```
s[r] #=> "Shadowborn Apostle "
```

See [MatchData#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

If the ending space is optional this is fine. If, however, the string *must* end with a space, we must make a slight adjustment to the regex:

```
r = /\A[^\r]+ /
```

Lastly, here is another way to obtain the desired substring that does not use a regular expression:

```
 idx = s.index(" \r")
   #=> 18
 idx.nil? ? nil : s[0, idx+1]
   #=> "Shadowborn Apostle "

 idx = "How now, brown cow".index(" \r")
   #=> nil
 idx.nil? ? nil : s[0,idx+1]
   #=> nil
```

See [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-index).

<sup>1 Why not a single backslash (`/^[^\]+/`)? Because Ruby would start the character class (`"["`), read 'negate' (`"^"`) an escaped right bracket `"\]"` (interpreted as the character `"]"`), and `"+"`. As the next character, `"/"`, terminates the regular expression, she would conclude that the character class was not closed and therefore raise an exception (`SyntaxError`).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to throughly explain the problem and solution. Have a great Sunday!